Questions on using the ページ counter
I am uncertain about a couple of things regarding the use of the ページ counter.
Firstly... How do I differentiate the use of the ページ counter to refer to "how many (pages)" vs "which (page)"?
The language learning app that I use (which admittedly doesn't get everything correct) refers to "page 2" as 二ページ.
However, Google Translate (which also doesn't get everything correct) says that:

"I am reading page 2 of the book" = 私は本の二ページ目を読んでいます
"The book has 2 pages" = この本は二ページあります

i.e.

"Page 2" = 二ページ目
"2 Pages" = 二ページ

Which is correct?
[EDIT] Taking out the first question above as @weeab00 has helpfully provided the link to an answer. (Leaving away the 目 suffix for ordinal numbers)
Secondly... ページ being a "loanword", does it follow 連濁 rules when combining with a number?
e.g. 六ページ - Is it pronounced ろくページ or ろっページ?

This question is similar to: Leaving away the 目 suffix for ordinal numbers. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does this page help? There is a 外来語 gairaigo section which includes ページ.

This question is similar to: How to pronounce 1ターン?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@broccoliforest Thanks, yes it does (in a way). The answer doesn't address ページ but from the examples, I would assume that (for 六ページ) both ろくぺえじ or ろっぺえじ works.

I don't have the rep to comment so I'll just post this as an answer. There don't seem to be many great resources for counters online so my go-to is just to find audio of the word being pronounced. In this case Forvo has a single pronunciation of ろくページ.
Slightly better, (if less convenient and frequently incomplete wrt. counters), if you use Anki the AJT Japanese plugin can download and search several offline dictionaries for entries which include readings and pitch accent information along with the audio file. In this case NHK-2016 lists a reading ロクページ with Pitch number 3 (associated with a file named 六ページ_ロクペ＼ージ_3_NHK-2016.ogg).
